# Has anyone worked on Decoding an Explicit Exchange FolderID to mine the internal information?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

When working with MS Exchange folders, particularly through EWS, everything hinges on the folderid which can be implicit or explicit.  Once the program obtains the explicit folderid, that ID identifies both the mailbox and the folder in that mailbox.  My assumption here is that the mailbox portion has to be encoded in the folder id, and (call it naivety) I believe anything encoded has to be decodable.

Has anyone attempted or succeeded in creating a utility that given a folderid would return the mailbox and folder name?

Answer (score 1):

The folder ID is intended to be opaque to the app.  We don't recommend you decoding it to figure out mailbox or folder name.  Thanks.

Comment: I understand the desire to hold the information, but it certainly makes great debugging sense when an application owner approaches the Exchange team with "Your email server got peanut butter in my chocolate!"  Being able to take their Sent Id that failed, and decode that to maybe some errant mailbox would stop further discussion as to blame.  Again, thanks for the perspective, but this seems like a very useful function.